# Is Copyright a Statute or Common Law and Why?

Tags: law, international-law, copyright

I'm not sure, but is Copyright a Statute or Common Law and Why? Does this vary between countries and why would it be either a Statute Law or Common Law? I need some help in this as I cannot decide which one would be appropriate to place a Copyright Law under.

Comment: What is it you are hoping find out with this question?  Copyright is a statute of law but the laws vary by country.

Comment: Well I was wondering if it was a Statute Law or Common Law. I'm not an expert you know. Please don't expect to much from my questions, I didn't really think it was stupid to ask this. :\

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you see as the differences between a statute and common law.  Copyright is a codified law it is not the result of  rulings if that is what you mean.  But the whole category of Copyright is far more complex than putting it in one or the other.

Comment: You need to specify a country.
This makes no sense as a international law question.
There is no such thing as international common law (is there?)

Comment: @Oxinabox Well, there is customary international law - not required by any treaty, but generally considered legally binding.

Comment: @cpast that is interesting. Thanks for letting me know. I should look into that.

Comment: This certiainly needs a country tag.  Can we assume "Japan" based on your profile page?  It should also probalby be asked at Law stack exchange, not here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belonds on law.se

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [copyright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright#Conception) and [statute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statute) can easily be looked up elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

My understanding is that in the United States copyright law is statutory. See Title 17 United States Code. I'm not really sure about copyright law outside the U.S.

I'm operating under the assumption that by common law you are referring to what is also known as case law.

Comment: So US have both common laws and statutory laws?

Comment: @SharenEayrs Yes.

Answer (score 4):

Copyright law was never a part of the Common Law.   [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_law_of_the_United_Kingdom#Background):

> The modern concept of copyright originated in Great Britain, in the year 1710, with the [Statute of Anne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statute_of_Anne). Under the Statute of Anne (1710), copyright term lasted 14 years plus an optional renewal of 14 additional years.

In the US,  [Article I, Section 8, Clause 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_One_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Section_8:_Powers_of_Congress) of the Constitution authorizes congress to pass copyright laws.    While some US states still recognize common law (in their constitutions), federal courts are not permitted to enforce it.

Today national copyright laws have been standardized to some extent through international and regional agreements such as the Berne Convention and the European copyright directives. Although there are consistencies among nations' copyright laws, each jurisdiction has separate and distinct laws and regulations about copyright.